# adding new variables to a existing dataframe using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataset which include the following variables:
ada_27, ada_28, ada_29, ada_30,....., ada_38
Each variable may have a value of 0, 1, or NA.

I want to create new variables ada_27_p, ada_28_p,..., ada_38_p (indicator variable whether each variable contains value of 0 or NA) using the following code:

```
dat$ada_@@_p <- ifelse((dat$ada_@@==0 | is.na(dat$ada_@@)),1,0)
# @@ is numbers 27 to 38
```

**I need help with puttin this procedure in for loop function** so that I do not need to write repetitive codes in R. Thanks!

I have trouble putting the above function in for loop as I do not know how to add newly created variables to the dataframe in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide some data next time. I created a simple version of your data.

You asked for a for loop. For loops across columns can be problematic. Since you're trying to work across columns, it's even easier to perform your desired operations across the columns with `across()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Small version of your dataframe
df <- data.frame(ada_1 = sample(v, 10, T), ada_2 = sample(v, 10, T), ada_3 = sample(v , 10, T), ada_4 = sample(v, 10, T))

# What it looks like
df
   ada_1 ada_2 ada_3 ada_4
1      1     0     1     0
2     NA     1     0    NA
3      0    NA    NA     1
4      0     0    NA     1
5      1    NA     0     1
6      1    NA     0     1
7      1     1     1     0
8      1    NA     1    NA
9     NA     1    NA    NA
10    NA    NA    NA    NA

# mutate() performs operations on data frame. across works across columns.
# Read the documentation for more details.
df <- df %>% mutate(across( ada_1:ada_4, ~ ifelse(. == 0 | is.na(.), 1, 0), .names="{.col}_p") )

df
   ada_1 ada_2 ada_3 ada_4 ada_1_p ada_2_p ada_3_p ada_4_p
1      1     0     1     0       0       1       0       1
2     NA     1     0    NA       1       0       1       1
3      0    NA    NA     1       1       1       1       0
4      0     0    NA     1       1       1       1       0
5      1    NA     0     1       0       1       1       0
6      1    NA     0     1       0       1       1       0
7      1     1     1     0       0       0       0       1
8      1    NA     1    NA       0       1       0       1
9     NA     1    NA    NA       1       0       1       1
10    NA    NA    NA    NA       1       1       1       1
```